# Where will this be allocated, stack or heap? (C++)

Tags: c++, object, heap-memory, new-operator, stack-memory

If I have the following code:

```
class xyzNode
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    // Other data
};
```

And in the main I do this:

```
xyzNode * example = new xyzNode;
```

I know that the object itself will be allocated on the heap because I'm using the "new" operator, but will the inner variables inside the object also be allocated on the heap? I just wanted to make sure because I'm not using the new operator for them.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes all the object along with it's member variables is going to be allocated on the heap.

Comment: You're making a distinction between "The object" and "it's inner variables" which does not really exist.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's feedback! :)

Comment: Hey, dear colleagues, why did you vote down this question? Yes, it *does* show the OP's *basic* misunderstanding, but how are such questions against the SO policy?

Comment: Honza, I think the question sounded too uninformed until I edited out a few lines. It's my fault, and I'll take better care next time. Thanks for your concern! :)

Comment: @HonzaZidek downvote doesn't mean "against policy". Hover mouse over the downvote arrow to see what it does mean. Questions that are against policy would get close-votes .

Comment: @Matt: I understand that the OP was **studying** some text but needed an extra help to understand its meaning. His question is far from the common stupid here-is-my-homework-do-it-instead-of-me questions! It does not show lack of the OP's own work. It seems to me that people in many SE sites are quite arrogant to beginners and vote down questions just because they consider them too trivial.

Comment: @Vladimir: your question sounds quite uninformed even now after your edit :-) but never mind! You have full right to ask beginners' questions! Understanding the stack vs. heap allocation of objects in C++ is quite a difficult topic, especially if you come from the world of another OO language where this distinction is not present.

Comment: I remember a seminar at my university on the Simula language back in the 1980's where a student who knew C++ asked the teacher about where the objects are allocated, and the teacher simply was not able to even understand the question itself! And of course the teacher *knew* what the stack and the heap was. But the idea of objects allocated on stack was completely alien to him.

Comment: @Honza I'll have to agree with you on that one, it's still pretty noobish hahaha! Maybe I should add the a "noob-question" tag to my post ;) But in all seriousness, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object's memory consists of its member variables, so those variables will exist in whatever memory block the object was allocated in.

```
xyzNode * example = new xyzNode;
```

This allocates a memory block on the heap that is large enough to hold a `xyzNode` object, then constructs the object within that block, and thus its members exist on the heap.

```
xyzNode example;
```

This allocates a memory block on the stack that is large enough to hold a `xyzNode` object, then constructs the object within that block, and thus its members exist on the stack.

Here is a less common example:

```
unsigned char buffer[sizeof(xyzNode)];
xyzNode * example = new(buffer) xyzNode;
```

The members exist on the stack, because `placement-new` is being used, and it constructs the object within the specified buffer, which is on the stack.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! And I had no idea about the `placement-new`, great to know! :)

Comment: @Remy: I would be scared to show the `placement-new` without clear warning what one may cause by using it! It's like giving a 7-year-old boy a loaded gun :-)

Comment: @Vladimir: If you allocate a buffer that is larger than available stack space, yes.

Comment: @Vladimir: Well, kind of :) It will not survive the scope of validity of the `buffer` variable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I guess I better make sure not to do that `;)`

Answer (score 3):

The Object (which is just its member variables plus some other information) is going to be placed on the heap, so the member variables will be there as well. The memory for the pointer `example` however, will be on the stack.